# Tanach with trop as plain text

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tanach, internet, text

Is there any place to download the Tanach, or at least the Torah, in plain text format, including nekudos and trop?  From Mechon Mamre I can download the HTML, but aside from the html tags the text is in a weird format (that I can't directly read in a text editor).

I'd like to be able to search for trop or sequences of trop, which is easiest in text format (with grep).

Comment: Feel free to borrow some of [my Node.js code](https://gist.github.com/Scimonster/4e47d57dd8d4b9875bae) to find gematriyas of Tanach - it uses Mechon Mamre's source, and filters out all of the HTML and other funny stuff.

Comment: @Scimonster That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Scimonster Out of curiosity, what "funny stuff" was there besides HTML?

Comment: Don't you have a problem with encoding or fonts by chance?

Answer (score 4):

A few options depending on what you're looking for:

- The [Leningrad codex](https://tanach.us/) is online including teamim. You can [download a zip file of everything in plain text format](https://tanach.us/Pages/Technical.html#zipfiles). Note that the teamim correspond to the WLC, and differ in some places from the commonly used ones.
- Wikisource has [the whole tanach](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A9:Dovi/%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94#%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA) and also has [an API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) which can be used to download in a variety of formats, including plain text. Wiki's teamim are based on the traditional teamim.
- Although it's not exactly what you asked for, you may also be interested in using [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/). It has an API and a download page for ever book which can be used to download JSON or csv. The leap from JSON or csv to plain text is not a big one and the organization may be helpful depending on what you're looking for. Sefaria's teamim are also based on the WLC.

Comment: To be more precise, Wiki's teamim are based on the [reconstructed] Aleppo Codex which still may differ (perhaps for the better!) in some ways from an average Chumash. (Not that any two Chumash editions are likely to ever be exactly the same.)

Comment: Dovi is using Mordechai Breuer's principles, to reconstruct the missing parts of the Aleppo Codex. There are also some corrections if an error can be assumed, and he's not retaining the chataf patachs. Everything is documented there.
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77548/hataf-patah-instead-of-shva-na-in-sephardic-and-ashkenazic-tikkunim/77625#77625