# Nikkud for Halleluyah

Tags: grammar-dikduk, prayer-book

I was learning to chant Tehillim in Israel last year. The Syrians have a tradition for how to chant psalms and they base their tradition off the Aleppo Codex.

In their siddurim, Halleluyah is written out as: "הַלְלוּיָהּ" and I have noticed this to be the case in most other Siddurim.

However, in the Aleppo Codex, it is written out as: "הַלֲלוּיָהּ"

Why the difference between the Shewa Na' and the Hataf Patah? I know the Hataf is usually placed under gutteral letters, but that does not seem to be the case here. Why do all of our siddurim show the shewa and not the hataf patah?

Comment: The Patah just means this Shva is Na even though it might not have been obvious that it should be. They didn't have a better way to indicate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77548/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you have sources for that? I've heard that they had a different pronunciation. Breuer et al. decided not to use this version to avoid confusing current readers.

Comment: Regarding the question, German siddurim kept this orthography, Böhmen-Mähren-Ungarn tried, but they are inconsistent

Comment: @kazi their shva na sound was more context dependant so it was probably more patach esque in in this context, but the general principle of using hatafs to mark shvaim naim that need help is true anyway. In a certain sense every hataf vowel is just a shva na that tends in the direction of a certain real vowel, usually one of an adjacent letter

Answer (score 3):

In Tiberian Hebrew, a shewa naʿ is by default equivalent to a hatef patah. Some masoretic manuscripts write this explicitly more frequently than others. One of the key features of the Aleppo Codex (A) is the frequency of explicit hatefim. Thus where the A has הַֽלֲלוּיָהּ, other mss have הַֽלְלוּיָהּ or הַֽלְלוּ־יָהּ. (Note that the gaʿya is present to indicate that the shewa is naʿ; were it not present, a simple gemination would occur.)

For example, Isaiah 10:1:

הַחֹקֲקִ֖ים חִקְקֵי־אָ֑וֶן (A)

הַחֹֽקְקִ֖ים חִקְקֵי־אָ֑וֶן ([Leningrad](https://tanach.us/Tanach.xml?Isa10:1-10:1) [gaʿya corrected], [Venice](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42690&st=&pgnum=19), [Codex Reuchlinianus](https://digital.blb-karlsruhe.de/image/tile/wc/nop/4049/1.0.0/3396516/3/2/1.jpg))

Ignoring the placement or existence of the gaʿya, the form הַחֹקְקִ֖ים is also found in the codices: Leningrad Firkovich 9, 25-26, 59, 124, 225, Cairo, and Sassoon 1053. It may even be the uncorrected form in A itself.

It is important to realize that the masoretic pronunciation is identical completely in any case: [haːḥoːqaqiːm ḥiqqeː'ʔɔːvεn]. In other reading traditions, however, the pair of words could be pronounced differently.

Israel Yeivin wrote a great book on the properties of the Aleppo Codex, called כתר ארם צובה: ניקודו וטעמיו.